# fetching embedded html document using c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I am developing a WinForm application that automate some tasks on an internal website "xyz.org", when I run the IE or chrome debugger on the website I get the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>....
<body>
  <outer code>....
  <div id="embedded">
  <iframe name="frame1" id="frame1" src="https://qwe.org" border="0" frameborder="0" style="height: 3675px;">
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
       <inner code>....
     </html>
  </iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So website xyz has some scripts that in the end call another website qwe.
I am using c#, I am using webBrowser control and I am trying to parse the "FULL" xyz & qwe html documents as showing in IE/Chrome debugger, here is my code:

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as  mshtml.HTMLDocument;
string html = doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

the html string in the end show the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>....
<body>
  <outer code>....
  <div id="embedded">
  <iframe name="frame1" id="frame1" src="https://qwe.org" border="0" frameborder="0" style="height: 3675px;">
  </iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So what is missing is the document code of qwe website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
       <inner code>....
     </html>
```

Is there a way to fetch that missing part of the embedded qwe website into the same html string, same as happening with IE/Chrome debugger

Answer (score 0):

you can try using c# CEF wrapper https://cefsharp.github.io/ to actually load the whole page and retrieve the code. There actually seems to be a subproject for the stuff that you need https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.OffScreen/

> CefSharp.OffScreen provides a "headless" browser control for
>   automation projects